# SQL how to remove duplicate results from same table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, vba

I created an sql table on visual studio for visual basic, where i can put dynamic data every time i click on a button. I get the table results from textboxes and one datagridview with values(quantity,price,discount). I use the "command insert values into" inside a for loop to be able to get all the datagridview results. The problem is that the table has rows with duplicate values. I want to remove the duplicate values and keep only the values from datagridview e.g I have a table with the following format:

[image]

Comment: I suggest you perform formatting for display purposes in the app code rather than T-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should work, tested in Memory table:

```
DECLARE @TBL AS TABLE
(   
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    First VARCHAR(10),
    Last VARCHAR(10),
    Address VARCHAR(30),
    Quantity INT,
    Price INT,
    Discount VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT @TBL (First, Last, Address, Quantity, Price, Discount )
    VALUES 
    ('rolp', 'Gaflp', '24 street', 1, 155, '10%'),
    ('rolp', 'Gaflp', '24 street', 3, 202, '5%'),
    ('rolp', 'Gaflp', '24 street', 4, 312, '6%');

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY First, Last, Address ORDER BY Quantity) AS Row
        FROM @TBL
    )
SELECT  ID, 
        CASE WHEN Row = 1 THEN First ELSE '' END AS First,
        CASE WHEN Row = 1 THEN Last ELSE '' END AS Last,
        CASE WHEN Row = 1 THEN Address ELSE '' END AS Address,
        Quantity, Price, Discount
    FROM CTE;
```